# Neovim: Can't bind ctrl+j to 7j or ctrl+k 7k using neovim with lua and iterm2

Tags: lua, neovim, iterm2

Im using Neovim with lua and iterm2 terminal and want to bind ctrl+j to 7j or ctrl+k 7k using neovim with lua and iterm2.

I've tried the following but its not working.

`keymap.set("n", "<C-k>", "7k", {remap = true, silent = true})`
`keymap.set("n", "<C-j>", "7j", {remap = true, silent = true})`

Using something like `keymap.set("n", "<C-a>", "7j", {remap = true, silent = true})` works, but its not wat I want.

Feels like there are some other keybindings in the way blocking ctrl+k and ctrl+j.

Answer (score 0):

try to use [which key](https://github.com/folke/which-key.nvim) to figure out the keybindings

Comment: Thx! Apparently I had tmux binding on those keys.